# Problems with file directories in Python

Tags: python

According to the readlink -f command in my terminal, the file that I'm currently in has the `path /home/pi/example.py`

The module I am trying to import into this file has the path `/home/pi/ReactiveEngine/src/PiEngine.py`

I have the following statements in my example.py file:

```
import os
os.chdir('/home/pi/ReactiveEngine/src/')
import PiEngine
```

But it's telling me that there's no module named **PiEngine** even though there clearly is. Am I doing something wrong or what could be giving me this error?

Comment: Why do you believe that your current directory affects what you can import?

Comment: I don't, just trying to be as clear as possible in my question by specifying file paths

Comment: try making it a module and import it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `sys.path` determines where files are imported from.  So I think you're looking for something like:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/pi/ReactiveEngine/src/')
import PiEngine
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add to the Python path at runtime using sys.path.insert()

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/pi/ReactiveEngine/src')
import PiEngine
```